# Отключить автоматическую обработку заголовка ETag

Tags: javascript, rest, header, xmlhttprequest

Я пишу приложение JavaScript на платформе Electron. Electron содержит в себе движок Chrome. 
Стоит задача получения котировок валют с определенного сервиса. Для этого в цикле отправляется один и тот же запрос. Ответ полученный после первого запроса содержит заголовок ETag. Движок автоматически обрабатывает ответ и в следующий мой запрос включает заголовок If-Non-Match. И если данные не изменились приходит ответ с кодом 304, это обрывает(или закрывает) установленное ранее соединение. На сервере котировок существует ограничение - 2 соединения в секунду. Поскольку котировки могут меняться несколько раз в секунду, отправлять запрос раз в секунду не вариант. Можно ли отключить автоматическое обработку заголовка ETag? а именно не включать заголовок включение If-Non-Match в последующие запросы?

Comment: Э... почему это вдруг ответ 304 закрывает соединение?..

Comment: да я не знаю, но после получения ответа соединение открывается заново, поэтому и предположил, хотя и в ответе и в запросе есть Connection Keep-Alive

Comment: @user185252, а вы ничего не путаете? Ограничение именно в два **соединения** или все таки в два **запроса** в секунду?

Comment: именно два соединения. запросов разрешают до 60 в секунду.